# Showing that $E[X|X<x]$ is smaller or equal than $E[X]$ for all x

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, conditional-probability, expectation

I would like to show that:

$\hspace{2mm} E[X|X<x] \hspace{2mm} \leq  \hspace{2mm} E[X] \hspace{2mm} $ for any $x$

X is a continuous R.V. and admits a pdf. I'm guessing this isn't too hard but I can't come up with a rigorous proof. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thomas has given a hint, but an intuitive explanation would be that you're putting an upper bound on the value of $X$ on the lhs, so the rhs would be at least as big as the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$E[X] = E[X|X<x]P(X<x) + E[X|X\geq x]P(X\geq x)$$

Also:

$$E(X|X<x)< x \leq E(X|X\geq x)$$

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this helps... could you give me further hints?

Comment: Added an additional hint, Vlad.

Comment: Yup! Got it! Thanks so much thomas