# Prove (or derive) $[X|X≤x]⩽x<[X|X>x]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

How can I prove (or derive) the following law on conditional expectation: $$[X|X≤x]⩽x<[X|X>x]$$
It appears in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/585219/418542) but I don't know where this identity comes from.

Comment: I just saw this presented in [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585214/showing-that-exxx-is-smaller-or-equal-than-ex-for-all-x] but I don't know where this comes from

Comment: @Harry49: I saw that claim ("note that"), and I can't figure out why can we make that claim? It's a general rule, and axiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** LHS says
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x sf(s)ds \le x\int_{-\infty}^x f(s) ds
$$
and in the LHS integral, $s <x$ because you are integrating over $(-\infty,x)$...

Can you finish this and do the RHS the same way?

**HINT 2**

Note that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x sf(s)ds
 \le \int_{-\infty}^x xf(s)ds 
 = x\int_{-\infty}^x f(s) ds
$$

Comment: I don't know how to finish this.

Comment: @Humberto see update

Comment: now I see! That's clear now.